# Как настроить CSS module в webpack без create-react-app?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, config, create-react-app

В базовой сборке `create-react-app` можно инкапсулировать CSS, добавив `.module`.

Плюс после сборки к ним применяется методология БЕМ, какие модули или еще что для этого нужны в `webpack`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вариант ниже предполагает использование как модульной так и не модульной загрузки стилей.

Лоадеры:

```
style-loader
css-loader
sass-loader    
// для autoprefixer и т.п
postcss-loader
```

Конфиг:

```
const cssRegex = /\.css$/
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/
const postcssConfigPath = "postcss.config.js"

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: sassRegex,
        use: [
          require.resolve("style-loader"),
          {
            loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1
            }
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
            options: {
              config: {
                path: postcssConfigPath
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve("sass-loader")
          }
        ],
        include: sassModuleRegex
      },
      {
        test: sassRegex,
        use: [
          require.resolve("style-loader"),
          {
            loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1
            }
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
            options: {
              config: {
                path: postcssConfigPath
              }
            }
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve("sass-loader")
          }
        ],
        exclude: sassModuleRegex
      },
      {
        test: cssRegex,
        use: [
          require.resolve("style-loader"),
          {
            loader: require.resolve("css-loader")
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
            options: {
              config: {
                path: postcssConfigPath
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        include: cssModuleRegex
      },
      {
        test: cssRegex,
        use: [
          require.resolve("style-loader"),
          {
            loader: require.resolve("css-loader")
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
            options: {
              config: {
                path: postcssConfigPath
              }
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: cssModuleRegex
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

так же для каждого загрузчика можно добавить source-map'ы и настроить обезличивание имен классов:

```
{
  loader: require.resolve("css-loader"),
  options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    importLoaders: 1,
    modules: {
      localIdentName: "z[hash:base64]"
    }
  }
}
```

названия которых будут "собираться" из того что будет указано:

```
localIdentName: "[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]"
```